# Microsoft Graph how to search contacts by emailAddresses with odata?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

Is there any way I can search by email in Contacts with Microsoft Graph?

```
/v1.0/me/contacts?$filter=emailAddresses/any(a:startwith(a/address,'john'))
```

The second one does not work as it required to enter the full address. 
Is the [documentation wrong](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_contacts)?

```
/v1.0/me/contacts?$filter=emailAddresses/any(a:a/address eq '@domain.com')
```

Comment: The docs are incorrect, it isn't possible to use `eq` with a partial string.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur Ah okey, do you know anything about the first question?

Comment: You need to use the full email address, it isn't possible to filter by domain.